# Symbolic logic for mathematicians, descriptor in symbolic languages

Tags: geometry, logic

I am trying to express only by means of symbols the next sentence:

"All line has an exterior point which is in a plane which contains the line".

I have reached many formalations, but I think that the best could be this:

[image]

where R=line, p=point, and P=plane.

As you can see, I used the sign "|". This sign works like a descriptor, and this sign is not very common in the texts on logic, but it exists. If anyone knows about a book where an axiomatization for logic is done and where the descriptor is included it will be very helpful if you comment it.

Now, If someone has an equivalent formulation it will be very helful to me, because I want to eliminate the descriptor.

is there a rule of descriptor elimination?

Thank you for your attetion.

Comment: It may help to move quantification up front for all the variables involved. "For all" lines $R$ "there exists" a point $p$ and a plane $P$ such that... and then list out all the properties you need joined with "and"s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Every line $R$ has an exterior point $p$ that is in a plane $P$ that contains the line" can be translated as:
$$\forall R \:\exists p \:\exists P \:(p\notin R \,\;\land\;\, p\in P \,\;\land\;\, R\subset P).$$

Incidentally, the "descriptor" $\:\mid\:$ is read "such that".

Your attempted formulation is wrong mainly because it doesn't capture the fact that $p$ is exterior to $R.$